# Query on labeling directions for electric force

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

On the second part of the problem, is my assumption correct? Do I even need to put the sign? or is the magnitude alone suffices as the answer?

Comment: \$|F_{21}|=|F_{12}|\$

Comment: I see. Thanks for the response.